# Sumif but different row of range critiria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

[image: https://i.imgur.com/DJidQjk.png]

As in screenshot, criteria is E3, range to search is B:B, sum in C:C. but a cell is over a row of range 1 row.

Best regard

Comment: Do not quite understand your question, your formula of `=SUMIF(B:B, E3, C:C)` seems to be correct. Care to elaborate further on the issue or what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Still finding an answer sir about problem is in picture
https://i.imgur.com/jK4fo8e.png
Sorry about how to clarify issue I am trying my best to describe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B1000, E3, C1:C999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `SUMIF` to calculate the total of certain values in a column of data. But you want to offset the criterion range by one row.

Use this formula:
`=sumif(offset(B8,1,0):offset(B100,1,0),E3,C8:C100)`

In this answer, `OFFSET` is used as a range value for both the criterion range.

**Criterion Range**
`offset(B8,1,0):offset(B100,1,0)`
The nominal range is B8:B100 (value="sell/buy"), but by offsetting one row the criterion becomes the value on the row **below** the nominal criterion (values ty[tp]/ty).

It isn't possible to specify the offset for an entire column (such as `B:B`), so both the criterion range uses the range - B8:B100.

Comment: Thank you very much. It work somehow but I still don't understand what behind, I will try to learn it :)

Comment: The answer by @player0 should be the accepted answer; it is much more elegant, simple and uncomplicated.